# How to fix "Polling for changes failed" in selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

- Geckodriver Version: 0.24.0
- Platform: Mac
- Firefox: 67
- Selenium: 3.14.0

While executing in firefox am facing this issue

```
console.error: BroadcastService: 
  receivedBroadcastMessage: handler for
  remote-settings/monitor_changes
  threw error:
  Message: Error: Polling for changes failed: http://%(server)s/dummy/blocklist//buckets/monitor/collections/changes/records?_expected=%221559138175738%22 is not a valid URL..
  Stack:
    remoteSettingsFunction/remoteSettings.pollChanges@resource://services-settings/remote-settings.js:203:13
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask].  It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  Can you add the (minimal amount of) code that reproduces this problem?  Just edit the question to add details.

Comment: @sankart Did you find a solution for this? The linked post doesn't help me too much and I got your exact same error message.